# Can a tremolo have a value of over one quarter note per note?

Tags: tremolo

I was wondering if tremolos can make a note separated into quarter notes. For example, a half note with a bar over it means to divide it into eighth notes, and a whole note with three bars over it means to divide it into thirty-second notes.

Is there any way to notate a note divided into quarter notes, as quarter notes don't have flags to denote as bars above a note?
Moreover, does the same apply to half notes, etc.?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @PiedPiper It’s just some weird music theory I’m willing to try out, I’m currently composing a piece with the meter of 16/4 and it’s Presto so I’m asking to make a tremolo so I don’t have to spam the chords 32 times

Comment: If you wrote it in 16/8 it would be much easier to read

Comment: Just change to 4/4 and adjust your note lengths accordingly, i.e. 16/4 quarter notes become sixteenth notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbreviation_(music)#Repetition_of_a_single_note_or_chord

...*divisi dots* can be placed over long notes to show quarter note repetition.

[image]

...you may want to confirm that with source other than Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

Basically no.  You'd need rather unusual meters for that to save a useful amount of space.  Remember that tremolo notation is a shorthand and can always be written out explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

PiedPiper and user65529 are right: why would you want to and basically no. But if you're familiar with *sim.* (*simile*) it might be useful. I can't really picture what you're doing though.

Answer (score 1):

Tremolo repeats cannot be used for notes as long as crotchets (quarter notes).

However, you could use simile slashes/percent repeats. For example:

[image: Slashes and Percent]